# bash script gives (unary operator expected)

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh root@192.xx.xx.xx netstat | grep 6200 > log

cnt=`grep -c 'EST' log`

if [ $cnt -eq 6 ]; then        
   echo working
fi
```

Result of

```
[root@xxx]# grep -c 'EST' log
6
[root@xxx]#
```

Comment: This should work fine. If I try your example, I get the output "working".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs when the **cnt** variable is empty. The if expression evaluates as 
**[ -eq 6 ]**

You can test this on the command line:

```
user@host:~$ [ -eq 6 ]    
-bash: [: -eq: unary operator expected
```

Also by adding **set -x** to the top of your script you can debug how it's being interpreted.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x

if [ $cnt -eq 6 ]; then        
   echo working
fi
```

---

```
./test.sh
+ '[' -eq 6 ']'
./test.sh: line 5: [: -eq: unary operator expected
```

Wrapping $cnt in double quotes "$cnt" fixes it as suggested because when empty "$cnt" evaluates to an empty string "".

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your script and it works if you double qoote cnt, it worked like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh root@X.X.X.X netstat | grep 6200 > log

cnt=$(sudo grep -c 'EST' log)

if [ "$cnt" -eq 6 ]; 
    then
         echo working
fi
```

I'd rather recommend to check your shell scripts in this [link](https://www.shellcheck.net/)

Comment: you are welcome... please vote or mark answer as valid if it helped you.